# 3D model looks right in Blender but loses textures on export to GLTF

Tags: animation, export, three.js

I'm struggling with readyplayerme + mixamo + blender + three.js. Below you see my character which I successfully (or so it seems) have animated by attaching a mixamo animation to my readyplayer me model. But that's where I'm getting off track because when I export this animated model to glb/gltf and play the animation with three.js but now only the legs and feet are visible...

I don't have much 3D experience and it seems to be my configuration in blender/exporting from so I was hoping you could help me out here.

reference: https:/rikwanders.nl (click on about on the left bottom of the screen to see the animation in play)

[image: Result when I export from blender to glb/gltf and play the animation with Three.js]

[image: Render in blender which is animating full character]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: It would be worth testing the model in a few online viewers if you haven't yet. https://sandbox.babylonjs.com/ and https://gltf.report/ for example. If the model looks correct in viewers, I'd ask for help on your three.js code in the three.js forums. If it's incorrect in viewers too you can file a bug on https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO.

Comment: Did you find a solution?